# Unit test for aws lambda using lambdaLayer with jest

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs

The path to my development directory is here.

```
.
├── README.md
└── business
    ├── jest.config.ts
    ├── nodeLayer
    │   └── db
    │       ├── README.md
    │       ├── dist
    │       │   └── db
    │       │       ├── index.js
    │       │       └── index.js.map
    │       │  
    │       ├── package-lock.json
    │       ├── package.json
    │       ├── src
    │            └── index.ts
    │       
    └── hoge1
        └── src
            ├── README.md
            ├── app
            │   └── app.ts
            ├── jest.config.ts
            ├── package-lock.json
            ├── package.json
            └── tests
                └── unit
                    └── get.test.ts
```

Import of hoge1/src/app/app.ts is here.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
import { Db } from '/opt/nodejs/dist/Db';
```

When I deploy and run Lambda, it runs without problems.

However, when I try to test with Jest, the following error occurs.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module /opt/nodejs/dist/db mapped as:
    ../../../../nodeLayer/db/dist/db/.
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/\/opt\/nodejs\/dist\/db/": "../../../../nodeLayer/db/dist/db/"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }
```

I can see that the import is not working properly.
I have set some options such as moduleNameMapper in the just.config.ts, but the error content is still the same.

```
// hoge1/src/jest.config.ts
export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    testMatch: ['**/tests/unit/*.test.ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '/opt/nodejs/dist/db/(.*)': '<rootDir>/../../nodeLayer/db/dist/db/$1',
    },
};
```

Is there a way to solve the Layer path problem?

[image]

PS

My earlier edit was incorrect.

I have changed the just.config.ts as follows.

```
export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    testMatch: ['**/tests/unit/*.test.ts'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['cf/.aws-sam/build'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^/opt/nodejs/dist/db(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../../nodeLayer/db/dist/db$1',
    },
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/nodeLayer/'],
};
```

Then the error became more detailed.

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:
    xxxx/business/nodeLayer/db/dist/db/index.js:2
    import { createPool } from 'mysql2/promise';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly guessed, `/opt/nodejs` is part of AWS layer. Hence why it works fine when you deploy and trigger the lambda.

But AWS layer doesn't exist in your local.

Hence you need to make sure `jest` correctly maps the import statement using `moduleNameMapper` in your `jest.config.{js|ts}`.

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '/opt/nodejs/dist/Db/(.*)': '<rootDir>/../../nodeLayer/db/dist/db/$1',
},
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
  '/node_modules/,
  '/nodeLayer/',
],
```

Comment: I used the method you suggested in business/hoge1/src/jest.config.ts, but the error still occurs.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: The command is executed under the `/business/hoge1/src` distribution.
So I expect `/business/hoge1/src/jest.config.ts` to be loaded.

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you retry?

Comment: Errors continue to occur.
Thank you for updating your response.

Comment: Updated answer again to add `coveragePathIgnorePatterns`. Can you check again?

Comment: I have updated my question.
It seems that the path set in moduleNameMapper is the path from the test file, and when I run it with the updated content, I get the same error as in my updated question.

Also, I added coveragePathIgnorePatterns and the error changed to this error.

"""Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/dist/Db' from 'app/app.ts'

    Require stack:
      app/app.ts
      tests/unit/get.test.ts"""Thanks for investigating the cause.

Comment: I have included new information in the addendum.
Please check it. Thank you.

Comment: You are not using the `moduleNameMapper` from my answer. Can you check again?